# Date format changed when exporting data to CSV from access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

When I export the data from access to a csv/text file, the date format gets changed automatically. In access query I have set the date format to be on "yyyy-mm-dd" but when I export to csv or text file, the date format gets changed to dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Don't export the table. Use a *query* where you force the format on the date field:

```
Select 
    <some fields>, 
    Format([TheDateField], "yyyy-mm-dd") As TextDate,
    <some more fields>
From YourTable
```

Save it, and then use this query for your export.